# INotifyPropertyChanged for EF CodeFirst Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, inotifypropertychanged

I am having trouble with INotifyPropertyChanged on navigation properties for Entity Framework Code First objects.  It is my understanding that this is a known problem: [reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532257/entity-framework-navigation-properties-don-t-raise-the-propertychanged-event).

I have seen some workarounds which tie into the AssociationChanged event for EF *generated* objects (example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/05/04/notifying-the-ui-when-entity-references-change-in-lookup-comboboxes.aspx)).  Since the class doesn't implement IEntityWithRelationships, trying to add this to the class doesn't work.  (I did try adding the interface with a virtual property, but this doesn't work because it is being accessed in the base class to provide notification.)

I have also tried adding notification for when the navigation property foreign key changes, but this doesn't seem to happen until the SaveChanges() method is called, which is too later for me.

Is there a Code First workaround?

Edit: For those who require code in every question, here you go:

```
public class SubAnalysis
{
    public virtual  Analysis Analysis { get; set; }

    // My attempt to add notification
    // Does not fire until too late (at SaveChanges?)
    public Guid AnalysisGuid
    {
        get { return this.analysisGuid; }
        set
        {
            if (this.analysisGuid != value)
            {
                this.analysisGuid = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("AnalysisGuid");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Analysis");
            }
        }
    }
}
```